# How can I use multiple texturing with shadow mapping?

Tags: opengl, texture, shadow-mapping

So, recently I followed this [tutorial](http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html) about shadow mapping, but in the tutorial it doesn't texture the object.. When I try to add a texture, it's distorted by the `TexGen`. Also I've tried to use `glActiveTexture()` with no success(dunno exactly how `glActiveTexture()` work).

So can anyone help me by adding textures into above code base? From there, I can learn how to use `glActiveTexture()` and overcome that `TexGen` issue.

Thanks in advance.. To note, I'm not using GLSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multi-texturing is supported, texture coordinate generation will affect the active texture unit (quote from the documentation, emphasis is mine):

> When the ARB_multitexture extension is supported, [glTexGen](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexGen.xml) sets the texture generation parameters **for the currently active texture unit, selected with glActiveTexture**.

So you simply need to make sure texture coordinates generation is disabled for the color texture, but enabled for the shadow texture. As you guessed, this is done with [`glActiveTexture()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml), by writing for example:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // Assuming the color texture to be #0
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); // Assuming the shadow texture to be #1
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(0));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
// [...]
```

---

This being said, you're adding to yourself a lot of trouble by sticking with fixed pipeline instead of using GLSL.